# Sound AVAudioPlayer not working

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to create a simple app that uses sound. I'm getting errors on my `AVAudioPlayer` function.

Here's what I mean:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController{
   var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   var playSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Bell", ofType: "mp3"))

   audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: playSound, error: &error)

   audioPlayer.play()

}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try to create a separate function.
try this..

```
func setupAudioPlayerWithFile(file:NSString, type:NSString) -> AVAudioPlayer  {
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file as String, ofType: type as String)
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
    var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer?

    do {
        try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
    } catch {
        print("NO AUDIO PLAYER")
    }

    return audioPlayer!
}
```

then run audioPlayer.play() wherever you want.